# How to evenly spread dots evenly on square container?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am trying to spread circles on a svg container like this:

```
const NewLockScreen = () => {
  const svgWidth = width - 24;
  return (
    <Container>
      <Svg
        width={svgWidth}
        height={svgWidth}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        {/* {new Array(9).fill(0).map((_e, i) => {
          const isOdd = (num: number) => num % 2;
          return (
            <Circle fill="red" key={i} r={23} cx={i * width} cy={10 * i} />
          );
        })} */}
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={svgWidth - 10} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2} />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
          cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
        />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={svgWidth - 10}
          cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
        />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={svgWidth - 10} />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
          cy={svgWidth - 10}
        />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={svgWidth - 10} cy={svgWidth - 10} />
      </Svg>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

current result is like this:[image]

I am curious how to achieve this result doing something like this from commented code?

```
 {/* {new Array(9).fill(0).map((_e, i) => {
              const isOdd = (num: number) => num % 2;
              return (
                <Circle fill="red" key={i} r={23} cx={i * width} cy={10 * i} />
              );
            })} */}
```

so that i will not have to do this?

```
 <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={svgWidth - 10} cy={10} />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2} />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
          cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
        />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={svgWidth - 10}
          cy={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
        />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={10} cy={svgWidth - 10} />
        <Circle
          fill="black"
          r={10}
          cx={(svgWidth - 5) / 2}
          cy={svgWidth - 10}
        />
        <Circle fill="black" r={10} cx={svgWidth - 10} cy={svgWidth - 10} />
```

Comment: The code is not much more prettier than the solution you've got unless you require dynamic properties (expanding points LxW). You commented code probably wouldn't do it nicely. There's a bit of conditions to be met. You need to divide by your width across, to get your increments to match up to the max-width of container and then determine if we're 3 or more tall to make sure we're doing the same. Loop central if you're good with that.

Comment: @blanknamefornow that's just a mock representation of a function i want to create, i am bad at math